# React re renders all items in array when new items are added despite using unique keys for all items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, rerender

### Original Post

I have a page that renders each item in an array contained in a redux state using Array.prototype.map. The array is initially populated when the componentWillMount() callback is called and is then appended when the user requests more data, i.e, when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page and if there are more items to be fetched. I make sure that the redux state is not mutated when the array is appened by using Array.prototype.concat(). However, when more items are added to the array, it seems like react re renders every item in the array, and not just the new items despite setting a unique key for each item. My source code for rendering the components is as follows:

```
this.props.state.list.map((item, index) => {
  return (
    <Grid className={classes.column} key={item._id} item xs={6} sm={6} md={4}>
      <Card className={classes.card}>
        <CardActionArea className={classes.cardAction}>
          <div className={classes.cardWrapper}>
            <div className={classes.outer}>
              <div className={classes.bgWrapper}>
                <img
                  className={[classes.bg, "lazyload"].join(" ")}
                  data-sizes="auto"
                  data-src={genSrc(item.pictures[0].file)}
                  data-srcset={genSrcSet(item.pictures[0].file)}
                  alt={item.name}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
              <div className={classes.textWrapper}>
                <div className={classes.textContainer}>
                  <Typography
                    gutterBottom
                    className={[classes.text, classes.title].join(" ")}
                    variant="title"
                    color="inherit"
                  >
                    {item.name}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    className={[classes.text, classes.price].join(" ")}
                    variant="subheading"
                    color="inherit"
                  >
                    {item.minPrice === item.maxPrice
                      ? `$${item.minPrice.toString()}`
                      : `$${item.minPrice
                          .toString()
                          .concat(" - $", item.maxPrice.toString())}`}
                  </Typography>
                </div>
              </div>
            </CardContent>
          </div>
        </CardActionArea>
      </Card>
    </Grid>
  );
});
```

Here's my reducer if you think it could have something do with that:

```
import {
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING,
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE
} from "../actions/products";

let defaultState = {
  list: [],
  cursor: null,
  calls: 0,
  status: null,
  errors: []
};

const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: "PENDING"
      };
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        calls: state.calls + 1,
        cursor: action.payload.data.cursor ? action.payload.data.cursor : null,
        list: action.payload.data.results
          ? state.list.concat(action.payload.data.results)
          : state.list,
        status: "READY"
      };
    case FETCH_PRODUCTS_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: "FAIL",
        call: state.calls + 1,
        errors: [...state.errors, action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

I read from answers to questions similar to mine that setting a shouldComponentUpdate() method for every component that is generated from the array might do the trick, but there are no clear examples as to how this can be done. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

### Edit 1

I should also specify that the components rendered from the array is completely unmounted and mounted again in the browser DOM when new items are added to the array. Ideally I would want the browser to never unmount existing components and only append newly rendered components.

### Edit 2

Here's the entire code for the component that renders the list.

```
class Products extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchNext, fetchStart, filter } = this.props
    fetchStart(filter)

    window.onscroll = () => {
      const { errors, cursor, status } = this.props.state
      if (errors.length > 0 || status === 'PENDING' || cursor === null) return
      if (window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop === document.documentElement.offsetHeight) {
        fetchNext(filter, cursor)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, title } = this.props

    return (
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Grid container spacing={0}>
          {
            this.props.state.status && this.props.state.status === 'READY' && this.props.state.list &&
            this.props.state.list.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <Grid className={classes.column} key={item._id} item xs={6} sm={6} md={4}>
                  <Card className={classes.card}>
                    <CardActionArea className={classes.cardAction}>
                      <div className={classes.cardWrapper}>
                        <div className={classes.outer}>
                          <div className={classes.bgWrapper}>
                            <img className={[classes.bg, 'lazyload'].join(' ')} data-sizes='auto' data-src={genSrc(item.pictures[0].file)} data-srcset={genSrcSet(item.pictures[0].file)} alt={item.name} />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
                          <div className={classes.textWrapper}>
                            <div className={classes.textContainer}>
                              <Typography gutterBottom className={[classes.text, classes.title].join(' ')} variant="title" color='inherit'>
                                {item.name}
                              </Typography>
                              <Typography className={[classes.text, classes.price].join(' ')} variant='subheading' color='inherit'>
                                {item.minPrice === item.maxPrice ? `$${item.minPrice.toString()}` : `$${item.minPrice.toString().concat(' - $', item.maxPrice.toString())}`}
                              </Typography>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </CardContent>
                      </div>
                    </CardActionArea>
                  </Card>
                </Grid>
              )
            })
          }
        </Grid>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If the state changes, a component and all its children rerender. This is so normal. But, rendering does not mean that those components will unmount/mount or destroyed/recreated again. This will occur only the changed parts. This is related to [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html). So, rendering is not so expensive, DOM manipulation is. But, if you are sure that rendering all those components creates some performance lost then you could check `shouldComponentUpdate` (be careful, sometimes touching it causes worse performance) or you can use PureComponent.

Comment: Hi @devserkan thanks for your comment. I think the DOM is being repopulated with array items that already existed when new items are added. When I test the page in Chrome and Firefox, the existing elements disappear and reappear when new items are loaded. Is this also expected behaviour?

Comment: If this is the case then I should learn more :) I thought only the rerendering happens in this case, not all the DOM manipulation. I know that React adds to or removes from the children but I did not think that all the DOM changes in that case.

Comment: That is what I expect as well. I'm pretty sure there's something I'm doing wrong. In any case thanks again for your comments

Comment: When you say disappear and reappear, do you mean the are going from visible to gone while loading? Are you doing anything with the status field on your reducer that would cause the list items to not show? Might be helpful to post the entire component code rather than just the list render.

Comment: @TLadd Yes they pop in and out. Chrome's page inspector also shows all existing elements disappear and reappear along with the updated content. I have also provided the code for the entire component in the most recent edit to the post.

Comment: you can write a `pure Component` to just render your map items and pass the items as props to that component and see whether the same thing is happening. for more reference https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html

Comment: did you get it or should add an example as an answer ?

Comment: @elemetrics I assume fetchNext ends up triggering FETCH_PRODUCTS_PENDING? That will cause the list to not render because of the condition `this.props.state.status && this.props.state.status === 'READY'`. Seems you could delete this check entirely and the pop out/in on load more should be fixed.

Comment: @aravind_reddy thanks for the suggestion. I am attempting it now. If I understand you correctly, I should write a separate react component for the parts that are being rendered by the map function. Say I create a component called: Item, then in the render method of my parent component I would just do something like:

list.map(item => {
  <Item key={item._id} />
})

?

Comment: @TLadd your suggestion rings of a certain validity. I'll try not setting the PENDING state and let you know. That's quite an oversight on my part. Thanks.

Comment: @elemetrics exactly use pure component for `Item` component but just remember that `pure component` performs just `shallow comparison` if  you have nested objects you should try to implement the componentShouldUpdate yourself. if you understand what i mean

Comment: @aravind_reddy Yep. I got it now. Thanks again.

Comment: @TLadd you nailed it. It was definitely the check for the PENDING status that was causing the entire list to disappear between fetches. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

So it turns out it was a conditional render that was causing the rendered list to disappear. In my case I set it so that the component would only render the list if all ongoing fetch operations had completed, so of course the list would disappear between fetch calls.

Changing the following from

```
    {
      this.props.state.status && this.props.state.status === 'READY' && this.props.state.list &&
        this.props.state.list.map((item, index) => {
          return <Item />
        }
    }
```

to this, thereby removing the check for the completed fetch state solved my problem.

```
    {
      this.props.state.list &&
        this.props.state.list.map((item, index) => {
          return <Item />
        }
    }
```